Technical specifications on SPL 404
I want to learn spl404 (how it works, how can I implement the logic etc.), however I could not find any technical document, developing guide or any tutorial. Are there any suggestion to deep dive into this topic ?

SPL-404 isn't a unified standard, and isn't apart of the official Solana Program Library.
Rather, it's a loose idea (saying standard would be generous) for NFTs that can be swapped to normal SPLs/Token22s. There aren't many public specs out for it yet because only a few teams have actually built swap pools for it (and they're closed source), plus there's a lot of variance in what standards are used for these programs (i.e some use pNFTs, original Metaplex standard, Nifty, etc...).
Here's a YouTube video from Abble which gives a high-level explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODUYbM9TNtA
